# Touch Screen for Clock

Tags: alarm, clock

I want my alarm clock fade to black, but when I touch the screen will display the time. I want to this feature at night when my clock is charging on my nightstand. Is there a way to achieve this type of feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can simply use *any* [alarm clock](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_alarmclocks) – and enable [Daydream](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/daydream/info) with either the digital or the analog clock. That would result in exactly what you're asking for:

[image: ConfigureDaydream] [image: DaydreamRunning]
<sup>Configuring Daydream / Daydrem in action (source: [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/170990/5-cool-uses-for-androids-daydream-mode/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

That's what I'm doing with my "good old Droid²" which serves as nightstand. You can even define how bright that clock should be (it has a special "night mode"). That way you're totally free to use the alarm clock of your choice.

Comment: That's great, thx! I didn't know Daydream would work that way.

Comment: Glad you like it! If it fits your needs, please signal that by "accepting" the answer (ticking the check-mark next to it). Btw: That clock in night mode is really very decent (not disturbing at all). Other than you requested, it would be on all the time (think of it as a screen saver) – and when you touch it, it would turn the screen saver off. I still think it's matching what you're after :)